# maven dependency for google checkout cannot be found

Tags: java, maven, google-checkout

I have a sample POM that shows the below code to be a working maven dependency descriptor and yet, this does not resolve. I have found absolutely NOTHING about why this might not work. I found one single question that was identical to mine and no answers.

Am I suppose to build it and host it in my own repository?? I can't find anywhere this repository exists. Anyone have some answers?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.checkout</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkout-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If it is not exist in any repos then how did you find this piece of dependency ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that this -- http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-java-sdk -- is the project you're talking about, it looks like it hasn't been updated in quite some time (last in September, 2010). The latest version in the Subversion repo there looks like it has a version of 2.5.0. There does appear to be a binary 2.5.1 version available [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-java-sdk/downloads/list), though.

What you're really looking for is the Maven repo, though. Unfortunately, Google hasn't really been very good about publishing their artifacts to Maven Central (let alone any publicly available Maven repo). I wasn't able to find anything in my search. (For future reference, http://search.maven.org is a fantastic resource, but keep in mind that's just a search through Maven Central.)

I'd suggest that you could maybe [download the source](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-java-sdk/source/checkout) and compile it yourself, but I tried that, and the project isn't even set up correctly. The build fails in the state that it's currently in.

If you take a look in the issues section, there is an [issue (#67)](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-java-sdk/issues/detail?id=67) that references the problems I listed above. That issue is dated June, 2010, so the problem has been around for a while. Someone was kind enough to attach a patch file recently (a few weeks ago). I did try using that patch against the latest code in the Subversion repository, and the build did work then. If you have access to an artifact repository like Artifactory or Nexus and you'd like to build the jar yourself, then that is an potential option.

Comment: Much appreciated. I read as you did but held out hope that there was a ready repository.